# Texture of object loading as black with dots and text

Tags: gazebo-11, ignition-fortress

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For some reason the texture on my mesh file loads as black for Gazebo 11 with ROS Noetic (gazebo fortress). The texture setup I have will load and configure perfectly fine for Gazebo garden on a different system with ROS2 Humble.. For some reason, when I load the same exact object into the predecessor version, the object renders with a black layer that has text and dots in it sometimes around the object. When I zoom in close onto the object, I can see through the black shielding layer and observe the true colors of the object. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28883/texture-of-object-loading-as-black-with-dots-and-text/) by [mmDrone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153458/mmdrone/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2023-03-16**:
Can you clarify if you're using Gazebo-classic (Gazebo 11) or Gazebo Fortress? Also, can you provide a minimal example that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The way the new Gazebo Garden loads models with textures is totally different to how it used to be. See "Textures" towards the bottom of this page: https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/3.7/migrationsdf.html

Took some creative google search to find this information. But the TLDR is instead of importanting a model texture the old OGRE way where you defined a `.material` file that ogre reads, you just import a MTL + OBJ or DAE file.

If you know how to use Blender it isn't too bad. You can create your 3D model with blender and then export it to MTL + OBJ (make sure you use PBR + Relative paths), or DAE (easier) file format. Then include the model as

```
<geometry>
  <mesh>uri://PATH_TO_MODEL</mesh>
<geometry>
```

^ where PATH_TO_MODEL is the folder name of your model with the appropriate model.sdf model.conf and other files.

---

Originally posted by [chutsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/482/chutsu/) with karma: 36 on 2023-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmDrone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153458/mmdrone/) on 2023-03-27**:
The documentation shared worked great for me. I used:

`<include> <uri> model://<model_name> </uri> </include>`

The texture is now loaded in properly. Thank you!